# What is the basic circuit to wire up a position-sensitive detector, or PSD?

Tags: breadboard, psd

I'm a software dev dabbling in electronics and I am looking into wiring up a position-sensitive detector, the Hamamatsu S3932, on a breadboard.

My knowledge is quite rudimentary and my first goal is to wire it up in a circuit without frying it. I am vaguely aware that diodes like a resistor, and that voltage regulators exist, but I have no idea how to take it from here. The [S3932 data sheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/bf5d/0900766b81540441.pdf) has a lot to say about the optical performance under various circumstances but I am unable to find anything understandable to me on how to operate it.

I am naively assuming that, after creating an appropriate circuit, I can then just take basic measurements with a multimeter but please do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Hit the [edit] link and add a link to the datasheet.

Comment: @Transistor done, thanks!

Comment: Here I found additional info ('Characteristic and use', starting from page 5): https://datasheet.datasheetarchive.com/originals/distributors/Datasheets-10/DSA-187740.pdf

Comment: @Seir awesome!

Okay so for my model I get: Interelectrode resistance 50 kΩ- so I'm thinking, if I power this with something like 5V, that's 0.0001A.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A linear PSD consists of two photodiodes. When you shine a small spot of light onto the PSD, the two photodiodes generate a current that is proportional to the distance between the light and each photodiode. As you move the spot closer to one end or the other, the balance of current generated shifts toward one photodiode or the other.

If you look through the datasheet, page 5 shows that the photodiodes have a common cathode. As such, the internal diagram of the PSD can be drawn like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKjHMy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The datasheet also has a section called "Conversion formula of spot light position on the PSD", which explains how to calculate the position:

[image: Screenshot from the datasheet showing the conversion formula]

Rearranging this for the distance from center, \$x\$, gives us:

$$x = \frac L 2 \times \frac{I_2-I_1} {I_1+I_2}$$

where \$I_1\$ and \$I_2\$ are the currents through photodiodes \$X_1\$ and \$X_2\$.

So, in order to figure out the position of the light spot on the PSD, you first need to measure the current generated through each photodiode. This is achieved by applying a reverse bias voltage through the photodiode, then measuring the current that flows using a transimpedance amplifier.

The datasheet indicates that an appropriate bias voltage is 5V. It also indicates that the photocurrent ranges up to 100µA when the light spot position is at its most extreme point on the sensor.

A circuit such as the following can be used to convert the 0-100µA current input into a 0-1V output:

[image: Circuit diagram]

You can simulate this [here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgoqoQFMBaMMAKAENxiVPvNuwuIPNSph48KLHgpspMtgyUiKACxkko8ZBYAnHuBTC+B4ZvgsA7iGNhD1jP0HarA-hkL7bpy-cfdsaPraAOb6aMKu1ggeVNoAlibg7onM3LFScGLSqnK5xHg+XkkekWDJ2gBKKbaJeLFQICq0DekILADG+nW+QvVgjGIgDDBZ6Dl5pDFSrC6C3aV2zj1Fxt3aAPIgAaKC2Ah+LSwA9gbgMY2Q+eDQKBrQEKIs2MIeAGIP1tD0TOniE-9yIYQAAKAAsjgAXI4AEziMLoAB0AM4AYQArjodHQAHYQlhAA). The photodiode current is adjustable via a slider on the right hand side of the page.

The equation for a transimpedance amplifier is as follows:

$$-I_{in} = \frac {V_{out}} {R_f}$$

Since we know \$I_{in}\$ is going be between 0 and 100µA, we can calculate a suitable feedback resistance for any given output voltage that we would like:

$${R_f} = \frac {V_{out}} {-I_{in}}$$

Substituting values in:

$$\frac {1V} {100µA} = 10000$$

This tells us we need a 10k ohm feedback resistor, which you can see in the circuit diagram above.

The capacitor is just there for filtering. 100pF is fine here.

In a practical design, your photodiode would be connected in place of the current source. The datasheet notes that a 1kΩ current limiting resistor should be placed in series with the photodiode.

Putting this together, you end up with something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1Wa3F.png)</sup>

Note: TL081 is just the default opamp in the editor, I haven't evaluated it to see if it's particularly suitable here.

From here you can read these voltages with a microcontroller and do the calculation yourself, or you could use a summing amplifier and differencing amplifier to find the sum and differences between the voltages in hardware, then read that with an MCU or use an analog divider to do the whole thing in hardware.

Comment: Holy smokes, I wasn't expecting this much help all in one place. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking you'll need two TIA or [transimpedance amplifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transimpedance_amplifier), one for the X1 and one for the X2 diodes, then some math.  To arrive at a position, the datasheet reads:

> If output current (photocurrent I1 and I2) are obtained from electrodes X1 and X2, then the position can be found from \$\frac{I_2-I_1}{I_1+I_2} = \frac{2\text{x}}{\text{L}}\$

The "spot size" for this sensor is microscopic - 200µm or 0.2mm... it might work with a bigger spot, I'm not sure but the datasheet was based on this size.

Comment: Thanks!!!

Spot size seems okay, I intend to use optics to focus a laser dot on it